# Почему возникает ошибка Undefined property: stdClass::$posterURL?

Tags: php

вот код

```
foreach ($qr as $q){
            var_dump($q);
        }
```

получаю

```
 object(stdClass)[63]
      public 'id' => string '991624' (length=6)
      public 'nameRU' => string 'Пол Фиг' (length=13)
      public 'posterURL' => string 'actor_iphone/iphone_991624.jpg' (length=30)
      public 'professionKey' => string 'director' (length=8)...
```

пишу так

```
foreach ($qr as $q){
            var_dump($q->posterURL);
        }
```

получаю `Undefined property: stdClass::$posterURL` почему не подскажите и как правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

значит на определённом моменте цикла его нет, могу только посоветовать сделать так для дебага

```
foreach ($qr as $q){
            if(!isset($q->posterURL) {
               var_dump($q->posterURL,$q);
            }
        }
```